# Laravel 5.4 Token Mismatch Exception on live server

Tags: laravel, redirect, token, centos7, mismatch

I am facing Token mismatch exception in Laravel 5.4 on live server. On my local machine running Windows XAMPP, the application works fine. When I deployed it to live machine running CENTOS 7 and LAMP stack, I see a redirecting to myhostname.com/login at the top left corner of the browser and then lands on an error page showing:

> token mismatch exception on line 68 of VerifyCsrfToken.php.

Comment: Simply clear the session folder, old sessions remain when the server is copied.
Also do a php artisan config:clear on your server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this same problem and what i did was:

First in your .env file remove: `SESSION_DOMAIN`
And in set session driver like: `SESSION_DRIVER=file` (if your want it to save to a file)

then do: `php artisan cache:clear`
then `php artisan config:clear

that worked for me.

Comment: I tried this but it did not work for me. Though I have seen this as answers but don't know why it did not work for me. I moved the same code to another server and everything worked fine.

Comment: in your page add `{{ csrf_token }}` then check the source code of the page to see if the crsf_token changes automatically each time you reload the page. If it does then its with your session domain but if it doesn't then it has something to do with your code.

Comment: I disabled CSRF middleware to track down the error but eventually noticed that logged in user is not being added to session.

Comment: enable the CSRF middleware and try the above method to see the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Try to clear config cache on the server with :

```
artisan cache:config
```

You will need to clear config cache also if you edited `config/app.php` for some reason.

In addition there is an other possible reason : you copied not only the application but also the cache/session files when you deployed your application to production. Basically everything in the storage folder should be ignored on deployment.