# How to solve "CSRF Token Mismatch" in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, csrf

I am working on a laravel application. Upon hosting it on my domain, I am running into a "CSRF token mismatch" error. Locally, the application is working fine because I have included the csrf token in the header as shown in the documentation. Therefore, the csrf token is being generated successfully and being included in the header of requests. On doing some debugging, I changed the `SESSION_DRIVER` in env file to `file` so that I can see the sessions. I realized that multiple sessions are being generated for one user. The `SESSION_LIFETIME` is set to `120`, which I believe is okay. In looking at the tokens in the sessions stored in `storage/framework/sessions`, none contains the token that is generated by the browser. What could be the issue? Remember that it is working fine locally. What configurations on the host domain could be affecting the sessions of the application.

Comment: you upload this project on live server recently? If so, then clear everyting `php artisan config:clear` , `php artisan route:clear` , `php artisan view:clear` , `php artisan cache:clear` then try again. I faced the same problem, after found that my liver server still using my local cache files, which i used fin development server

Comment: The session is loaded by reading the session cookie and finding the session with the corresponding session id. If the cookie is not sent or contains a session id that expired then a new session is created. I would take a look at how the session cookie looks like first of all

Comment: I just realized that every reload, which means a new request, a new token is generated. I realized that by inspecting the meta element that has the csrf token. This only happens in the live server. How can i sort that? What could be the issue considering that it is working fine locally?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel 5.4 Token Mismatch Exception on live server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46279779/laravel-5-4-token-mismatch-exception-on-live-server)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I once ran into the same error while hosting in the cPanel and took me almost 3days to figure out the solution for my case.
I do not know if this works for you but give it a try.

Inside your main index.php file inside the public folder, edit it and at the very top after starting PHP tags, write

```
ob_start()
```

This function will take the contents of the output buffer and returns a string that is to be sent to the browser for rendering and removes the spaces or line breaks you put before starting PHP.

Also, try clearing the cache as suggested in the comments.

Let me know if this helps you as well.

Comment: but what dould be the proble? i had a same issue on my server laravel project

Comment: The problem can be something like spaces or line breaks at the very beginning of your php files before you even start the php tags or something more similar to this.
This perhaps results in the error as in the question.
For more detail information, you can research on why ob_start is used at the very beginning of the php files.

Answer (score 4):

Add the following line to the head tag.

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}"> // Add in <head></head>
```

Then get you can get this content attribute in Laravel. Also, in your script tag, add the following code (this is to make sure when you submit the form, you get the correct `csrf_token`).

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

I had this very same problem, receiving the "CSRF Token Mismatch" exception in Laravel 7, having fixed everything else, like setting the csrf token on page header, in ajax requests, clearing the cache, anything you can think of and usually find in solution proposals.

So, if anyone ever runs into this, I haven't found this solution anywhere else, and it really cost me hours.

I had called the application on the wrong URL!

I used my local IP literally, instead of using the word "localhost".

So, if you're developing locally, calling you app with your IP, try calling it on http://localhost!

Comment: Thank you – this was really helpful! In my case, wthe culprit was the redundant trailing forward slash in `APP_URL` in `.env` file!

Answer (score 0):

Unlike @cslotty, in my case I actually had to change my URL from 'localhost' to '127.0.0.1' for it to work. My frontend is in React and the backend in Laravel 8.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue. I found the solution in Laravel document itself.

We can add `$csrf` after the form element

```
<form method="POST" action="/profile">
@csrf

  //input fields here
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the "CSRF token mismatch" error appears in the program for other reasons. For example, I received this error when I wanted to upload a very large file (about 1G). When I tested with a smaller file, the program worked fine.
To solve the problem, go to the file

```
app/Http/Kernel.php
```

and temporarily disable the `VerifyCsrfToken` middleware (from the `$middlewareGroups` section). Then test again. Probably the error will change.

In my case, the problem was that the permission of that file was wrong and actually the server had no problem!

Don't forget to re-enable `VerifyCsrfToken` middleware after the problem is solved.