# csrf_token error in virtual host in Ubuntu

Tags: laravel, ubuntu-18.04, virtualhost

My laravel project working fine on 127.0.0.1 but when trying to run on a virtual host I am getting a csrf_token mismatch error.

This is my .conf file code

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@server.in
    ServerName test.local
    ServerAlias test.local
<Directory /var/www/html/test/development/public>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/test/development/public/
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Have you searched SO? Take a look at this answer, maybe it helps you aswell: [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62967643/9636400)

Comment: Thanks for your reply but ob_start() didn't work.