# CSRF token mismatch error when calling api.php routes with swagger

Tags: php, laravel, postman, swagger

**Please note this question is about API routes in api.php which don't have CSRF protection, I know how CSRF works but I'm not using web routes here so there shouldn't be any CSRF check.**

I'm writing a backend API for a vue application.
I'm trying to use swagger instead of postman for API documentation and testing.

My backend is php/laravel and I'm using a JSON file to run my swagger.

For some reason when I test my API routes with swagger I get:

> CSRF token mismatch error

[image]

```
curl -X 'POST' \
  'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/csadmin/partners/create' \
  -H 'accept: application/json' \
  -H 'Authorization: Bearer {token}' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -H 'X-CSRF-TOKEN: ' \
  -d '{
  "name": "ourpartner",
  "contact_name": "contact_ourpartner",
  "email": "ourpartner@gmail.com",
  "country_id": 1,
  "city": "santa monica",
  "zip_code": "1234",
  "phone": "+14845101873",
  "address": "some address",
  "membership_status": "a"
}'
```

Request URL

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/csadmin/partners/create
```

Response

```
419
Undocumented
Error: unknown status

Response body
Download
{
  "message": "CSRF token mismatch.",
  "exception": "Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Exception\\HttpException",
  "file": "C:\\wamp64\\www\\myproject\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Exceptions\\Handler.php",
  "line": 379,
  "trace": [
    {
      "file": "C:\\wamp64\\www\\myproject\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Exceptions\\Handler.php",
      "line": 353,
      "function": "prepareException",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Exceptions\\Handler",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "C:\\wamp64\\www\\myproject\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php",
      "line": 51,
      "function": "render",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Exceptions\\Handler",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "C:\\wamp64\\www\\myproject\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
      "line": 185,
      "function": "handleException",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "C:\\wamp64\\www\\myproject\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Session\\Middleware\\StartSession.php",
      "line": 121,
      "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "C:\\wamp64\\www\\myproject\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Session\\Middleware\\StartSession.php",
      "line": 64,
      "function": "handleStatefulRequest",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Session\\Middleware\\StartSession",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "C:\\wamp64\\www\\myproject\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
      "line": 180,
      "function": "handle",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Session\\Middleware\\StartSession",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "C:\\wamp64\\www\\myproject\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Cookie\\Middleware\\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php",
      "line": 37,
      "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "C:\\wamp64\\www\\myproject\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
      "line": 180,
      "function": "handle",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Cookie\\Middleware\\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "C:\\wamp64\\www\\myproject\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Cookie\\Middleware\\EncryptCookies.php",
      "line": 67,
      "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "C:\\wamp64\\www\\myproject\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
      "line": 180,
      "function": "handle",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Cookie\\Middleware\\EncryptCookies",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "C:\\wamp64\\www\\myproject\\vendor\\laravel\\sanctum\\src\\Http\\Middleware\\EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful.php",
      "line": 26,
      "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "C:\\wamp64\\www\\myproject\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
      "line": 162,
      "function": "Laravel\\Sanctum\\Http\\Middleware\\{closure}",
      "class": "Laravel\\Sanctum\\Http\\Middleware\\EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "C:\\wamp64\\www\\myproject\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
      "line": 116,
      "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "C:\\wamp64\\www\\myproject\\vendor\\laravel\\sanctum\\src\\Http\\Middleware\\EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful.php",
      "line": 34,
      "function": "then",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "C:\\wamp64\\www\\myproject\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
      "line": 180,
      "function": "handle",
      "class": "Laravel\\Sanctum\\Http\\Middleware\\EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "C:\\wamp64\\www\\myproject\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
      "line": 116,
      "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "C:\\wamp64\\www\\myproject\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php",
      "line": 726,
      "function": "then",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "C:\\wamp64\\www\\myproject\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php",
      "line": 703,
      "function": "runRouteWithinStack",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "C:\\wamp64\\www\\myproject\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php",
      "line": 667,
      "function": "runRoute",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "C:\\wamp64\\www\\myproject\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php",
      "line": 656,
      "function": "dispatchToRoute",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "C:\\wamp64\\www\\myproject\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel.php",
      "line": 167,
      "function": "dispatch",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "C:\\wamp64\\www\\myproject\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
      "line": 141,
      "function": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\{closure}",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "C:\\wamp64\\www\\myproject\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest.php",
      "line": 21,
      "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "C:\\wamp64\\www\\myproject\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull.php",
      "line": 31,
      "function": "handle",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "C:\\wamp64\\www\\myproject\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
      "line": 180,
      "function": "handle",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "C:\\wamp64\\www\\myproject\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest.php",
      "line": 21,
      "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "C:\\wamp64\\www\\myproject\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TrimStrings.php",
      "line": 40,
      "function": "handle",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "C:\\wamp64\\www\\myproject\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
      "line": 180,
      "function": "handle",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TrimStrings",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "C:\\wamp64\\www\\myproject\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ValidatePostSize.php",
      "line": 27,
      "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "C:\\wamp64\\www\\myproject\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
      "line": 180,
      "function": "handle",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ValidatePostSize",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "C:\\wamp64\\www\\myproject\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance.php",
      "line": 86,
      "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "C:\\wamp64\\www\\myproject\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
      "line": 180,
      "function": "handle",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "C:\\wamp64\\www\\myproject\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Http\\Middleware\\HandleCors.php",
      "line": 62,
      "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "C:\\wamp64\\www\\myproject\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
      "line": 180,
      "function": "handle",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Http\\Middleware\\HandleCors",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "C:\\wamp64\\www\\myproject\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Http\\Middleware\\TrustProxies.php",
      "line": 39,
      "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "C:\\wamp64\\www\\myproject\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
      "line": 180,
      "function": "handle",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Http\\Middleware\\TrustProxies",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "C:\\wamp64\\www\\myproject\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
      "line": 116,
      "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "C:\\wamp64\\www\\myproject\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel.php",
      "line": 142,
      "function": "then",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "C:\\wamp64\\www\\myproject\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel.php",
      "line": 111,
      "function": "sendRequestThroughRouter",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "C:\\wamp64\\www\\myproject\\public\\index.php",
      "line": 52,
      "function": "handle",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "C:\\wamp64\\www\\myproject\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\resources\\server.php",
      "line": 16,
      "function": "require_once"
    }
  ]
}
```

same route works fine in postman

[image]

I've no idea what is going on.

Comment: Please check this post's answers.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62967224/how-to-solve-csrf-token-mismatch-in-laravel

I think they are talking about the same problem.

Comment: @NairiAbgaryan these are api routes , they dont require CSRF token and dont have CSRF protection

Comment: Are your API routes in `api.php`? Seems like you're defining them in `web.php` based on the middlewares that are loaded.

Comment: @KimHallberg yes  in `api.php` , i know this is the wierd part ... the front is a `vue` application ... i dont have any front routes ... also it works fine in postman

Answer (score 2):

Fixed this issue by updating file **app/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php**

Add `/api/*` item to `$except` array:

```php
protected $except = [
  "/api/*"
];
```

Comment: I might be wrong but completely disabling all CSRF check should be avoided. Maybe temporarily ok, but not in production.

Comment: For API endpoints CSRF is redundant.

Answer (score 1):

i also faced same problem. After checking through all round i found series of solution depending on the laravel version.

for older versions you may try. Add it to the web route

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function () {
Route::get('api/documentation', '\L5Swagger\Http\Controllers\SwaggerController@api')->name('l5swagger.api');
```

});

For Laravel 8. Add the code below to your l5swagger.php. default-route-middleware-api

```
\Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
\Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
\App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
\Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
```

Answer (score 0):

This is working fine with cookie-base-auth
at first do not forget to call {{url}}/sanctum/csrf-cookie and then

import this line in `resources/views/vendor/l5-swagger/index.blade.php` to get a csrf-token cookie

```
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/js-cookie@3.0.5/dist/js.cookie.min.js"></script>
```

then add this code in `const ui = SwaggerUIBundle({`

add

```
requestInterceptor: function(request) {
 request.headers['accept'] = 'application/json';
 request.headers['X-XSRF-TOKEN'] = Cookies.get('XSRF-TOKEN');
 return request;
},
```